# FTP software that tracks hashes of files uploaded last time to speed upload

Tags: ftp

Is there any FTP software (I currently use FileZilla on Windows) that hashes all files uploaded... so next time uploading a file os million files... it compares files to hashes and only upload changed/new?

If the software supports command line that would be even greater but not a must for now.

Answer (score 1):

The most robust is probably [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp). It will track changes to files in your folder using `git`, and will only copy files modified since the last push. It can be more complicated to run if you want to mirror in both directions though

---

If you're fine with using dates only instead of full hashes, you could use something simpler like `lftp` to only copy newer files and cache the file listing. Example based on the answer here: https://serverfault.com/a/24833/411612

```
lftp -c "open ftp://user:password@your.ftp.com;  
lcd ./web; 
cd /web/public_html;
mirror --reverse --delete --use-cache --verbose --parallel=2"
```

Comment: I will check git-ftp. I won't think dates will be sufficient here since I may have regenerated the files (but just with the same content)

Answer (score 0):

the FTP protocol does not support the message exchange required to do this. It can't provide the client a list of hashes of the existing files.

It's theoretically possible that the client software or the server software could do this, but for the client, it must already have the entire set of files locally to hash and compare, and for the server the upload must be made before the hashes could be calculated, so without a means to retrieve hashes from the server in order to facilitate a client side check, there's just no way to make it feasible.

Here is a list of operations available via the FTP protocol:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands

Comment: If the software using FTP for upload stored hashes of files in a local database after upload: Then upon next upload, the software would have access to hashes of files it uploaded last time. Hence it can compare/hash the local files and compare against own local database copy of hashes calculated on prior upload. This would allow only uploading the new files. (That is the solution I have in mind coding myself. It of course assumes then all upload of files go through that single mechanism. And if something happens at server it all breaks. Many caveats and not ideal. But better than no solution.)

Comment: that is true, but predicated on the assumption that only one party has access to the server for uploading, and you can thus assume that all hashes are exactly the same as the server version of the files hash. its not an impossible task if you can write your own rules, as you mention, but you won't find software that already does that, and even if there was something, we don't do software recommendations on this site.